# Database Connection limit exceeded in shiny app using pool package

Tags: r, shiny, pool, rds

I have my shiny app in AWS ubuntu server and i am using mysql as database in rds server. To connect to my database using shiny app i am using pool package. But when i run my app several times it is showing error   **Cannot allocate a new connection: 16 connections already opened**
syntax which i am using to connect to mysql is

```
pool <- dbPool(drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),dbname = "db",host = "database.c.us-east- 
 2.rds.amazonaws.com",username = "host",password = "host", port = 3306)
```

I have tried this **poolClose(pool)**  but this does not work.Further i have tried various possibilities available on internet but nothing worked.